# Would the moon doom a particle accelerator attached to the ISS?

Tags: space-constructs

The International Space Station(ISS) is by far the most expensive man-made object money can buy and yet we cast it into space, set in near future government threatens to pull out funding for ISS and give it to high energy particle research instead due to recent (re)discoveries at LHC(Europe) in the past couple of years. To save ISS the science community decided to conduct particle collision in space with the help of ISS, we will attach several modules in series spanning approximately 1 kilometer long to house a linear particle accelerator. Since it will become the longest man-made object ever put into space I'm actually more concern about the effect of tidal force during a moon flyby, or am I paranoid?

Comment: Why would you want to spend all that extra money to do the collisions in space? It won't likely teach you anything new.

Comment: Do you know how expensive that would be?  Most countries don't have that amount of money in their treasury...

Comment: @Erik in order to create energy of 3 TeV we need 4Km long tunnel and my proposal will not only save ISS it will also save space for future experiments.

Comment: @Neil this is set in the future and I believe a breakthrough in 3D printing and probably [inflatable space elevator](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/11805987/Inflatable-space-elevator-invented-by-scientists.html) investors will flock in all over the globe in the name of science.

Comment: @user6760 One thing has been constant, and that's that you don't see anything done unless there's strong incentive.  Even in the future it'll be convenient to build it on earth, unless that changes of course, but I can't imagine a reason why.

Comment: cum? Mmh, I'm not sure what the moon is trying to do to the ISS, but it will likely be NSFW.

Comment: @Lohoris those ISS scientists are so nasty!

Comment: Just build a particle accelerator on Iapetus. It already has a straight mountain ridge circling it that woudl fit a particle accelerator perfectly ;)

Comment: One kilometer is peanuts to pretty much any astronomical object out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? There is already 3 miles at SLAC. Gravity is not a problem for accelerators. You want shielding around the detectors, so put them under ground!  You also need power.

As for the effects of a 1km tether, just by being a non-point mass, look up "space tethers".